# What size pipe to use when hooking up 2 dryers

Tags: dryer

How to hook up two dryers with what size exhaust pipes horizantal

Answer (score 1):

Don't combine pipe, you may get back-flow if one dryer isn't in use.

Instead, run 2 separate lines.